# Undefined variable: expenses_category in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I tried to edit the data been fetched from the database in laravel by passing the id through the url but everytime I click the url to go to edit page I received:

```
"Undefined variable: expenses_category (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Tailor\core\resources\views\expensesCat\edit.blade.php)"
```

Link to the edit.blade

```
<a href="{{ url('admin/editCat',[$expenses_category->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</a>
```

Here is the edit.blade

```
@section('content')
<div class="portlet light bordered">
    <h3 class="page-title">Expenses Categories</h3>

   {!! Form::model($expenses_category, ['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['updateCat', $expenses_category->id]]) !!}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Edit
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <input name="order_create_by" type="hidden" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                    {!! Form::label('name', 'Name*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::text('name', old('name'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) !!}
                    <p class="help-block"></p>
                    @if($errors->has('name'))
                        <p class="help-block">
                            {{ $errors->first('name') }}
                        </p>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    {!! Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

For web.php

```
Route::get('/editCat/{id}', 'ExpensesCategoriesController@editCat');
```

for ExpensesCategoriesController

```
public function editCat($id)
    {
        $expenses_category = ExpensesCategory::findOrFail($id);

        return view('expensesCat.edit', compact('expenses_categories'));
    }
```

What could have been the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `controller` function to this -

```
public function editCat($id)
{
    $expenses_category = ExpensesCategory::findOrFail($id);

    return view('expensesCat.edit', compact('expenses_category'));
}
```

You need to use same variable name in compact too.